# Delete from next line of matching to end of file with sed

Tags: sed

I want to use `sed` to match a line, preserve the matching line and delete all lines under. Or in other words, I want to extract the text from beginning

Sample input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Sample match RegEx: `/^3$/`

Sample output:

```
1
2
3
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
seq 5 | sed '/^3$/{n;,$d}'
```

I also tried this but it will delete the matching line, which I want to preserve.

```
seq 5 | sed '/^3$/,$d'
```

Any ideas with `sed` (I can't use AWK for miscellaneous reasons)?

Comment: Never mind... I just found a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `q`*uit* command:

```
 seq 5 | sed '/^3$/q'
```

Comment: Great! This does exactly what I want and is unarguably better than my self-answer!

Comment: Also, if you want to also delete the matched line, use `Q` (instead of `q`): `seq 5 | sed '/^3$/Q'`

Answer (score 1):

Think the other way round: Print from beginning to matching line, which does the equivalent of deleting lines under.

```
seq 5 | sed -n '1,/^3$/p'
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```